# Prestashop, custom module, Get SQL value for the configuration form with $helper->fields_value

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I'm currently creating my first Prestashop module, and I use the native function $helper to generate my configuration forms.

I'm ok when using the basic fonction "Configuration::get" but because the limited size of the table ps_configuration, I use a new sql table, and I wish to load the data of this table in my form.

Actually my module contain that code when querying the ps_configuration table :

```
$helper->fields_value['ZC_PREFOOTERBAND_DATA'] = $ZC_PREFOOTERBAND_DATA;
```

And I tried to query my customtable like this :

```
$query='SELECT `data`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customtable`
        WHERE `option` = \'ZC_PREFOOTERBAND_DATA\';';
$sql = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query);
```

But my form still blank, I can't get my sql data.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I did a misstake with my variables ...
To many variables, that's don't help ^^'

So the right solution to get the sql value is that one :

```
$query='SELECT `data`
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customtable`
WHERE `option` = \'ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA\';';
$ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA = Db::getInstance()->getValue($query);
$helper->fields_value['ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA'] = $ZC_HEALTHBAND_DATA;
```